# Get unsigned bytes in Java

Tags: java, byte

Is there any way to read bytes in Java and to have the same "format" result than in C#?

Indeed in Java, bytes are signed (-128, +127), where in C# it's not (0, 255).

I'm sending files with a java application to a server who is expecting only positive bytes, so it's not working as soon as I have some negative bytes.

Concrete problem : when I'm serializing my bytes[] into json (using gson), I have values from -128 to + 127 whereas I'd like to have value from 0 to 255.

Hope it's clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'positive byte'. A byte is 8 bits. The difference is _how you represent numbers_ with bytes. C# bytes are unsigned using plain ol' base 2 and java bytes are between -128 to 127 using 2's complement. 11111111 and 11111111 are the same byte both in C# and java.

Comment: [Please tell more about the concrete problem for which you incorrectly thought that this is the solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BalusC : I edited my problem it was not clear indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get [0-255] values in the Java app, use a construct like `(b & 0xff)` to get a positive `int` from a `byte`.

Answer (score -2):

Java byte is signed from -128 to 127, if u want to get the representation from 0 to 255 i use this 2 functions

```
public static byte fromIntToByte(String value) throws Exception {
        return fromIntToByte(Integer.parseInt(value));
    }

    public static byte fromIntToByte(int value) throws Exception {
        String stringByte = "";
        if (value < 0 && value > 255) {
            throw new Exception("Must be from 0<=value<=255");
        }
        if (value <= 127) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                stringByte = String.valueOf(value % 2) + stringByte;
                value = value / 2;
            }
        } else {
            value = value / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                stringByte = String.valueOf(value % 2) + stringByte;
                value = value / 2;
            }
            stringByte = "-" + stringByte;
        }
        System.out.println(stringByte);
        byte b = Byte.parseByte(stringByte, 2);
        return b;
    }
```